# How to make Firefox show a desktop notification by running a script through it (like a website would)?

Tags: scripts, firefox, notification

I am needing to test a bug where Firefox 47 does not show desktop notifications for the majority of the time even when a site is meant to be making it generate them (this wasn't present in previous Firefox versions).

Now the problem is that I want to do this in a VM, but I don't want to log into any of the sites that generate them in the VM. So is there any way I can make some sort of script or something which I can run/open in Firefox which would do the same as a website telling it to show a desktop notification?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: (Still) on mobile, but we would need to find out what html code firefox is triggered by to send a notification command. Mayby look into the code of a html page that *should* call a notification, then create a local html page, open it with firefox.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Found and posted the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a desktop notification appear put this code into a file whose extension you should put as `.html`, then run it using Firefox. Double-clicking it should do the trick in most cases.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type='text/javascript'>
var RunOnDomReady = function() {
function authorizeNotification(){Notification.requestPermission(function(perm){alert(perm);});}
function showNotification() {
 var notification = new Notification("This is a title", {
     dir: "auto",lang: "",body: "This is a notification body",tag: "sometag",
 });
}
document.querySelector("#authorize").onclick = authorizeNotification;
document.querySelector("#show").onclick = showNotification;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){RunOnDomReady();}, false);
</script></head><body><button id="authorize">Authorize notification</button><button id="show">Show notification</button></body></html>
```

When the page loads up in Firefox you will need to press the `Authorize notification` button, then you can press the `Show notification` button.

---

- [Direct Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1131277)
- [Indirect Source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/hidpi-support-html5-notifications-parallel-js-asm-js-and-more-firefox-development-highlights/)